# Ansible get column from stdout

Tags: ansible

I'm new to Ansible an thus this question may seem silly to more advanced users.

Anyway, I need to get the value `362496` for the column `LDFree`.

I know I can use the `shell module` with `pipes and awk`, but I was wondering if it's posisble to achive it in Ansible using some sort of "filter" for STDOUT?

This is the STDOUT from the CLI:

```
       -------------------------(MB)-------------------------                      
   CPG ---EstFree---- -------Usr------- ---Snp---- ---Adm---- -Capacity Efficiency-
  Name RawFree LDFree    Total     Used Total Used Total Used   Compaction    Dedup
SSD_r6  483328 362496 12693504 12666880 12288 2048  8192 1024          1.0        -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can done this knowing the fact that Ansible/Jinja support calling methods of native types:

```
- command: cat test.txt
  register: cmd_res
- debug:
    msg: "{{ cmd_res.stdout_lines[3].split()[2] }}"
```

`stdout_lines[3]` – take forth line, `.split()` – split it into tokens, `[2]` – take third token.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there will be some other way to do this.